# Как использовать переменную созданную в классе php?

Tags: php

В общем вот код:

```
class User extends CI_Controller {

public static $logged_in = false;


  public function register() {
  if($logged_in == true){
  $this->view("auth/register");
    }else{
            $this->view("404.php");
        }

  }
```

Но при запуске говорит : Undefined variable: logged_in
Как исправить?!

Comment: Обращение к статическим переменным происходит через `self`. В вашем случае - это `self::$logged_in`

Comment: Рекомендую прочитать главу про обращение к переменным класса http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php

Answer (score 2):

Нужно использовать `self::$logged_in` вместо `$logged_in`.